# Docker port conflict on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, port, xdebug, docker-network

- I am using Ubuntu and trying to config remote debugging with Xdebug (debugger for PHP) to work on a Docker container.

  ```
  trungdq88@ubuntu:~/# ifconfig
  docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:7b:c2:ec:97  
            inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::42:7bff:fec2:ec97/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:8923 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:13333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
            RX bytes:5099353 (5.0 MB)  TX bytes:16082560 (16.0 MB)

  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ca:3a:d3:4f:03  
            UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
  ```
- My container **exposes port 9000** (Xdebug's working port).

  ```
  EXPOSE 80 443 9000
  ```
- Since docker machine in Ubuntu **is the same as the real machine**, the `docker-proxy` process takes the 9000 port

  ```
  trungdq88@ubuntu:~/# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :9000
  tcp6    0    0 :::9000    :::*     LISTEN      10391/docker-proxy
  ```
- My IDE (Sublime Text) can't start the debug session because it needs to listen on port 9000 as well.

  ```
  trungdq88@ubuntu:~/# echo "Assume that this is my IDE" | nc -l -p 9000 
  nc: Address already in use
  ```
- I tried another port:

  In Ubuntu:

  ```
  trungdq88@ubuntu:~/# echo "Hello" | nc -l -p 12345
  ```

  Inside Docker container:

  ```
  root@919737061a1d:/src# telnet 172.17.0.1 12345
  Trying 172.17.0.1...
  Connected to 172.17.0.1.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  Hello
  Connection closed by foreign host.
  ```

  (It works on port 12345)
- My `docker-compose.yml`:

  ```
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "9000:9000"
  ```

`Dockerfile` sets entry point to a `sh` script which run the services (php-fpm, nginx...). I use `docker-compose up` to run the container.

**My questions are:**

- Is it necessary to expose ports when using Docker in Ubuntu?
- How can I get my IDE debug feature to work if `docker-proxy` keep listening on port 9000?
- I didn't expose port 12345 in my container but why the last example (netcat and telnet) still works?

Comment: Could you provide your `docker run` command please?

Comment: @Auzias I use `docker-compose up` to run the container, I have edited my question (add `docker-compose.yml` content).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it necessary to expose ports when using Docker in Ubuntu?

Yes, or the port would not be opened at all.
See [Dockerfile `EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The `EXPOSE` instruction informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime.
>   `EXPOSE` does not make the ports of the container accessible to the host. To do that, you must use the `-p` flag to publish a range of port.

So you also need to publish it in order to be accessible from the host:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000
```

(from [`docker run -p hostPort:containerPort`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports))

If that port is inconvenient (because if has to be used by XDebug) you need to change the host port (meaning, internally in the container, you can keep using 9000)

```
docker run -p 1245:9000
```

Comment: The IDE need to listen on the port that debug information from the container pass through, in this case `9000`. If we map `9000` in the container to `1245` in the host, isn't that mean the IDE will not receive anything on port `9000`? And IDE can't listen on `1245` since `docker-proxy` is listening on it?

Comment: "Yes, or the port would not be opened at all." - Could you provide a link to a document that mentions about this?

Comment: @TrungDQ "If we map 9000 in the container to 1245 in the host, isn't that mean the IDE will not receive anything on port 9000?" Yes, so in your case, do map to port 9000.

Comment: @TrungDQ "Could you provide a link to a document that mentions about this?": I have edited the answer.

Comment: I am sorry if I didn't explain the problem clear. When I map the port as `9000:9000`, there is a process called `docker-proxy` in the host **listening on** `9000`, which make my IDE **unable to start the debug session** (because it has to listen on 9000 as well). Same thing happen if I use `1245:9000` mapping.

Comment: @TrungDQ any possibility to configure your IDE to listen to another port?

Comment: Say I configure the IDE to use `3333`, in that case I need to map `3333:9000` to be able to receive debug information from the container (or.. is it?). If I map `3333:9000`, the `docker-proxy` will listen on `3333` whenever the container starts, then the IDE can't listen to `3333` anymore. Well, feel like running in a paradox here. I'm thinking maybe I do not need to expose the `9000` port because in Ubuntu the host and the containers is sharing the same network, but I have to wait until I got home to try it out. Uhh.. and If you got time, I am willing to continue this discussion on chat.

Comment: @TrungDQ Why the docker-proxy would listen on 3333? (No chat: blocked at work)

Comment: It just happens, I don't know clear about this part of docker. But from my question, you can see the result of `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :9000` is telling `docker-proxy` is listening on whatever the port that configured in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: @TrungDQ Could you configure your docker dameon to desactivate that proxy? (see comment in http://serverfault.com/a/638993/783)

Comment: @TrungDQ What docker version are you using by the way?

Comment: Uhh... I'm not sure about deactivate that proxy, is it the right solution for this case? Do you think we can send a package from container to host without need of exposing the port? Like the last example in my question, I was able to use telnet and netcat to communicate through `12345` port. I'm away from home so I can't tell the exactly docker version I'm using on that Ubuntu, but it probably 1.9.1 in my memory.

Comment: @TrungDQ yo will still expose the port. Just change the config of the daemon.

Comment: @TrungDQ And make sure to use docker 1.10.1

Comment: I will try to config the daemon as the link you provided, as soon as I get home. Is there any obviously changes from 1.10.1 related to this that I missed?

Comment: @TrungDQ The image format has changed (http://162.242.237.67/docker-blog/2016/01/docker-1-10-rc/, https://blog.docker.com/2016/02/docker-1-10/)

Comment: For the docker daemon settings: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/. Or https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/configuring/#ubuntu: `/etc/init/docker.conf`

Comment: Thank you for your time and the information. I'll get back to this as soon as I got any update.

Comment: @TrungDQ have you had any luck getting this to work?  I am having the exact same issue.  I have the exact same set up as you.

Comment: @WesleyMusgrove Unfortunately I didn't had chance to get back on this. If you have any progress on this please let me know too. Thanks.

Comment: @TrungDQ I posted on this issue https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug/issues/63.  Maybe it will get some traction.  Surely there are more people trying to use sublime, xdebug, and docker.